# How do I pass a variable inside a POST request URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url, google-apps-script, fetch, google-sheets-api

I am trying to pass a variable that is derived from a database (and keeps changing) to a fetch URL. I don't want to hard code it in the URL. How do I go about it? Here is the snippet of the code.

```
  };
  var searchString = amount;
  var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'payload' : data,
  };
  var url = 'https://......./**amount**/budget_items?token';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

I want to pass the **search string variable** but I don't know-how. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include `searchString` in the `url` you can use string concatenation or string interpolation. Here is string concatenation:

```js
var url = 'https://.../' + searchString + '/...';
```

And here is string interpolation:

```js
var url = `https://.../${searchString}/...`;
```

Comment: Hey Matt, Actually I tried this and it returned invalid arguments. I think i forgot to note that this is a POST request

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending a `GET` request, you must include the query arguments in the URL. You don't have to hardcode anything - just add the query parameters in the fetch itself:

`` var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + `?search=${searchString}`); ``

If you're trying to send a `JSON` object, you should instead use `POST`. You'll be able to preserve the URL as it is (as long as it's accepting `POST` requests). You'll be able to send `JSON` in the `data` option too.

Comment: Hey Shawn, actually it is a post request. How can I use a POST, kindly show me

Comment: In your `options` object add 
`headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}`

Comment: Also, instead of `payload`, use `body`

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically include `searchString` in the URL string you can use Matt's method, but you have some problem with your code. You are passing the wrong payload. Here is the modified code you can use it.

```
   };
  var searchString = amount;
  var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    payload
  };
  var url = `https://......./${searchString}/budget_items?token`;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

To know more about [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `URL` object (needs polyfills in IE)

```js
const url = new URL('http://foo.bar/?search');
url.searchParams.set('search', searchString);
```